# How to join 2 csv files with a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to make a shell script that will combine two csv files in the following way:

I have two csv files, f1.csv and f2.csv. The format of f1.csv is:

```
startId, endId, roomNum
```

f2.csv has a format like this:

```
startId, endId, teacherId
```

I want to combine these two into one csv file with this format:

```
startId, endId, roomNum, teacherId.
```

What is the best way to accomplish this with a shell script that runs under Linux?

Comment: Did you try Google search "bash merge columns textfile"?

Comment: The question is not complete. Nobody (included answers already here) can give a correct answer, until you specify all margins. For example, what if here are no pairs, what if here are common startid, but different endid and so on. Without these, all solutions will be only best guess. (or, you can define: is already ensured than both files are same count of lines and both files has identical "startid;endid" and files difers only in 3rd column (room,teacher).)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
join -t, -1 1 -2 1 -o 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.4 <(awk -F, '{print $1":"$2","$0}' f1.csv | sort) <(awk -F, '{print $1":"$2","$0}' f2.csv | sort)
```

How it works:

1) I first create a composite key column, by joining the startId and endId into startId:endId for both files.

```
awk -F, '{print $1":"$2","$0}' f1.csv
awk -F, '{print $1":"$2","$0}' f2.csv
```

2) I sort both outputs:

```
awk -F, '{print $1":"$2","$0}' f1.csv | sort 
awk -F, '{print $1":"$2","$0}' f2.csv | sort
```

3) I then use the `join` command to join on my composite key (in the first column) and output just the columns I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," '{print $1","$2","$3",9999"}' f1.csv > newFile;
awk -F"," '{print $1","$2",9999,"$3}' f2.csv >> newFile
```

let me explain whats happening here -F"," specifies a comma as the field-separator.

for the missing column i replaced with the text 9999 you can replace with whatever you like. the firs command is redirecting stdout to a file called 'newFile' and the second command is appending stdout to the same file.

I hope this helps, your question was not to clear with what you wanted to do with the missing field from each file.

Comment: -1 You're appending files instead of joining them on specific columns

Comment: The question ultimately calls for a new file.  A field to join on was not specified. We are to assume the startID's are unique for f1.csv and f2.csv. This is a perfectly proper answer. No? For example, see jm666's comment to the original question. My answer was neither correct or incorrect. The same can be said about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join -t ';'` to combine the corresponding lines. The parameter to the -t option depends on your CSV field separator (typically a semicolon). See the rest on the manpage of join. If you need to trim down duplicate columns later on, use `cut` for that.