# Linux - join 2 CSV files

Tags: linux, join, csv

I have 2 CSV files:

```
file_1 columns: id,user_id,message_id,rate
file_2 columns: id,type,timestamp
```

The relation between the files is that `file_1.message_id` = `files_2.id`.

I want to create a 3rd file that will have the following columns:

```
file_1.id,file_1.user_id,file_1.message_id,file_1.rate,file_2.timestamp
```

Any ideas on how to do this in Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301059/how-i-can-join-two-csv-files

Comment: its not the same, in the answers there they are appending the rows instead of the columns

Comment: Do you want `file_1` prefixed to every column in your final file?

Comment: yes, in the end the out put should look like file_1 with the addition of 1 column from file 2 (timestamp)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`join`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(Unix)) command like this:

```
join -t, -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.3 <(sort -t, -k 3,3 file1) <(sort file2)
```

It first sorts the files (`file1` is sorted by the 3rd field) and then joins them using the 3rd field of `file1` and the 1st field of `file2`. It then outputs the fields you need.

Comment: im getting: join: file 2 is not in sorted order
join: file 1 is not in sorted order

Comment: even when you run it thru the sort command as shown in dogbanes solution ?  (sort <file1>)  only the <file1> is changed, include sort!

Comment: there's probably a bug here... afaik join only works if the files are sorted by the join key. since you're calling sort on file1, it will be sorted by column 1 which is not the sort key

Comment: this should probably be changed to the following command... `join -t -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.3 <(sort -t $',' -k 3,3 file1) <(sort file2)` in order to sort by the correct join key

Comment: @PradeepGollakota almost. You forgot the comma in `join -t, ...`. Also, I think `sort -t $','` and `sort -t,` are equivalent, but the latter variant is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a job for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Using the [SQLite shell](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html):

```
 create table f1(id,user_id,message_id,rate);
 create table f2(id,type,timestamp);

 .separator ,
 .import 'file_1.txt' f1
 .import 'file_2.txt' f2

 CREATE INDEX i1 ON f1(message_id ASC); -- optional
 CREATE INDEX i2 ON f2(id ASC);         -- optional

 .output 'output.txt'
 .separator ,

 SELECT f1.id, f1.user_id, f1.message_id, f1.rate, f2.timestamp
   FROM f1
   JOIN f2 ON f2.id = f1.message_id;

 .output stdout
 .q
```

Note that if there is a single error in the number of commas in a single line the import stage will fail. You can prevent the rest of the script from running with `.bail on` at the script beginning.

If you want unmatched ids you can try:

```
SELECT f1.* FROM f1 LEFT JOIN f2 on f2.id = f1.message_id WHERE f2.id IS NULL
```

Which will select every row from `f1` for which no corresponding row in `f2` has been found.

Comment: I hesitated to initially comment "use a proper database," but this seems to do the job with the database as a temporary mechanism. +1

Comment: each file has about 70M records, i think it will be "hard" for the db

Comment: @Ran: absolutely not if you create indexes. `CREATE INDEX i1 ON f1(message_id); CREATE INDEX i2 ON f2(id);` You can create indexes after the `.import` stage. If those column values are unique you can declare them as `PRIMARY KEY` in the create table statements, then no need to use indexes. Use `.bail on` to exit at the slightest error.

Comment: @Ran: but note that if you have lots of data it's probably more efficient to use an intermediate database file. Run `sqlite foo.db` instead of `sqlite`.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can try something like this -

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]","$3 > "file_3"}' file_1 file_2
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file_1     # Contents of File_1
id,user_id,message_id,rate
1,3334,424,44

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file_2     # Contents of File_2
id,type,timestamp
424,rr,22222

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]","$3 > "file_3"}' file_1 file_2

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file_3     # Contents of File_3 made by the script
1,3334,424,44,22222
```

Comment: i dont need the "file_1." in the output file, it was just to show from which file i need each column

Comment: Ok thank god coz that was getting a little messy. I have updated the answer. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @Ran I did a test with a sample data. Looks like it works. Let me know if you run in to any issues or if you don't understand anything and I will walk you thru it.

Comment: is awk the right solution if each of the files have ~80M records?

Comment: It basically boils down to how much time you want to invest. A good solution would be to write an efficient program in compiled language rather than a interpreted. You can give it a try and see the performance. With faster machines, performance of a interpreted/scripting language isn't that bad.

Comment: and how about using `join` ? any ideas how to do it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
1. Change all lines to start with the key:

```
awk -F',' { print $3 " file1 " $1 " " $2 " " $4 } < file1 >  temp
awk -F',' { print $1 " file2 " $2 " " $3 }        < file2 >> temp
```

Now the lines look like:

```
message_id file1 id user_id rate
id file2 type timestamp
```

1. Sort `temp` by the first two columns. Now related lines are adjacent, with `file1` first

   `sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2 < temp > temp2`
2. Run `awk` to read the lines. In `file1` lines save the fields, in `file2` lines print them.