# Merge two tables in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two tab separated data files like below:

file 1:

```
number  type    data_present
 1       a        yes
 2       b        no
```

file 2:

```
type    group   number  recorded
 d       aa      10       true
 c       cc      20       false
```

I want to merge these two files so that output file looks like below:

```
number  type    data_present    group   recorded
  1      a         yes           NULL    NULL
  2      b         no            NULL    NULL
  10     d         NULL           aa     true
  20     cc        NULL           cc     false
```

As you can see, for columns which are not present in other file, I'm filling those places with NULL.

Any ideas on how to do this in Scala/Spark?

Comment: This is a type of cross join or perhaps a union but prepping the data is the tedious part.  How far have you gotten? Can you post some spark code?

Answer (score 3):

Create two files for your data set:

```
$ cat file1.csv 
number  type    data_present
 1       a        yes
 2       b        no

$ cat file2.csv
type    group   number  recorded
 d       aa      10       true
 c       cc      20       false
```

Convert them to CSV:

```
$ sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' file1.csv | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' ',' > f1.csv
$ sed -e 's/^[ ]*//' file2.csv | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' ',' > f2.csv
```

Use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) module to load CSV files as dataframes:

```
$ spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df1 = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> "f1.csv", "header" -> "true"))
val df2 = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> "f2.csv", "header" -> "true"))
```

Now perform joins:

```
scala> df1.join(df2, df1("number") <=> df2("number") && df1("type") <=> df2("type"), "outer").show()

+------+----+------------+----+-----+------+--------+
|number|type|data_present|type|group|number|recorded|
+------+----+------------+----+-----+------+--------+
|     1|   a|         yes|null| null|  null|    null|
|     2|   b|          no|null| null|  null|    null|
|  null|null|        null|   d|   aa|    10|    true|
|  null|null|        null|   c|   cc|    20|   false|
+------+----+------------+----+-----+------+--------+
```

For more details goto [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html), [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframe-operations) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

Comment: What if the resulting join is too big to fit on memory.  How can I do it directly on disk?

Comment: @skan: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820778/linux-join-2-csv-files

Comment: but this doesn't make use of Spark

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the desired output:

```
val output = file1.join(file2, Seq("number","type"), "outer")
```

Comment: Facing similar problem , tried this but getting : found : Seq[String] required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149483/error-while-doing-outer-join-on-2-data-frames-spark-scala-sqlcontext

Comment: @user3407267 i think your ques has already been answered by zero323 are you still facing the prob??

Answer (score 0):

Simple convert all columns into to String, than do union on two DF.