# How to join a CSV file and connect the rows with the matching content

Tags: csv, sorting, join, export-to-csv

I got 3 CSV files and they all have "company names" as a column. How can i join the 3 files and match rows with the same company name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - join 2 CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820778/linux-join-2-csv-files)

Comment: I have absolute 0 knowledge of Linux. Maybe you can give me another oppurtunity?

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail to be able to give you more information. This is almost definitely something that should be solved with `awk` which is a programming language all it's own. There is a chance that if you can share some sample data for the three files (check out http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for formatting ascii text tables) and what your desired results would be after joining, that someone may be able to whip up an awk script that will do the job for you. If you are going to be doing more of this type of work, then I would totally invest in learning awk.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 CSV Files.

- 1st: Companies which has columns "company_name", "phone", "mail" etc.
- 2nd: Contacts which has columns "contact_company_name", "contact_phone", "contact_mail" etc.
- 3rd: Messages which has columns "message_company_name", "message_phone", "message_mail" etc.

I would appreciate it some1 would give me an awk example. I will check out the language by now.