# How to merge two files with different fields based on one matching columns?

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files as below and I want to merge them into one file based on common IDs:

File1:

```
ARS     8.0   8.0
BBL     1.1   1.2
CCL     1.9   1.8
```

File2:

```
ARS     2.3   2.4
ARS     2.6   2.4
ARS     2.5   2.3
BBL     1.9   1.8
EDE     1.4   1.6
```

Desired output:

```
ARS     8.0   8.0    ARS     2.3   2.4
ARS     8.0   8.0    ARS     2.6   2.4   
ARS     8.0   8.0    ARS     2.5   2.3
BBL     1.1   1.2    BBL     1.9   1.8
CCL     1.9   1.8    NA
NA                   EDE     1.4   1.6
```

Comment: Are those tab-separated fields or fixed-width or some number of blank chars or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - join 2 CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820778/linux-join-2-csv-files)

Comment: They are all tab-spaced.

Comment: Can `ARS`, for example, appear multiple times in file1 just like it can in file2? If so include a case like that in your example.

Comment: JNevil, That is different

Comment: Ed Morton, No, duplicates are just in file 2.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46345345/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.(I have kept the order of NA at last only let me know if this helps you).
Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$0;
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print a[$1],$0;
  b[$1];
  next
}
{
  print "NA\t",$0       
}
END{
  for(i in b){
    delete a[i]
};
  for(j in a){
  print a[j],"\tNA"
}
}
' file1  file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ARS     8.0   8.0 ARS     2.3   2.4
ARS     8.0   8.0 ARS     2.6   2.4
ARS     8.0   8.0 ARS     2.5   2.3
BBL     1.1   1.2 BBL     1.9   1.8
NA   EDE     1.4   1.6
CCL     1.9   1.8   NA
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh The second one worked BUT I want NA in the right columns to recognise which file it belongs to so say if ID only comes from file 1, NA should appear on the right side in output. (have a look at my question). Here EDE should appear on the right and NA on the left and the opposite for CCL.

Comment: @Behmah, please check my edited solution now and let me know.

Comment: It didn't change :(

Comment: When I am running my code I am getting same output as I mentioned in my post, let me know if you are running exactly same code?

Comment: You are sure you make the edition in the code above?

Comment: yes, 110% I re-ran it again and same shown output which I mentioned in my post.

Comment: sorry Ravinder it works for this example but not for my actual file maybe because my actual file is tab-space ??

Comment: ahhh apologies for it, try adding -F'\t" after awk and let me know then, edited code now too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155012/discussion-between-behmah-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: Thank you Ed, but in above one of the comments OP mentioned in CCL it should be NA in left most side so I changed my code as per the same.

Comment: I apologies Ed, I really overlooked it, I edited my code now with output(specially NA's place)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
FNR==1 {
    na = $0
    gsub("[^"FS"]","",na)
    nas[++numFiles] = "NA" na
}
NR==FNR { file1[$1] = $0; next }
$1 in file1 { print file1[$1], $0 }
{ file2[$1] = $0 }
END {
    for (key in file1) {
        if ( !(key in file2) ) {
            print file1[key], nas[2]
        }
    }
    for (key in file2) {
        if ( !(key in file1) ) {
            print nas[1], file2[key]
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ARS     8.0     8.0     ARS     2.3     2.4
ARS     8.0     8.0     ARS     2.6     2.4
ARS     8.0     8.0     ARS     2.5     2.3
BBL     1.1     1.2     BBL     1.9     1.8
CCL     1.9     1.8     NA
NA                      EDE     1.4     1.6
```

There's various ways it could be optimized to not store the whole contents of both files in arrays but I like the simplicity and symmetry of the above and it's trivial to optimize later if that proves to be necessary due to massive input files.

Comment: `^1` liked the way you used `gsub`

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool for merging files

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e NA t24.in1 t24.in2  -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3
```

output:

```
ARS     8.0     8.0     ARS     2.3     2.4
ARS     8.0     8.0     ARS     2.6     2.4
ARS     8.0     8.0     ARS     2.5     2.3
BBL     1.1     1.2     BBL     1.9     1.8
CCL     1.9     1.8     NA      NA      NA
NA      NA      NA      EDE     1.4     1.6
```