# How to do divide a column based on the corresponding value in another file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have multiple files (66) and want to divid column 3 of each file to its corresponding value in the info.file and insert the new value in column 4 of each file. 
My manual code is:

```
awk '{print $4=$3/NUmber from info.file}1' file
```

But this takes me hours to do for each individual file. So I want to automate it for all files. Thanks

```
file1:
 chrm  name  value
 4     a      8
 3     b      4

file2:
 chrm  name  value  
 3     g      6       
 5     s      12       

info.file:
 file_name    average
 file1          8
 file2          6
 file3          10
```

output:

```
 file1:
 chrm  name  value  new_value
 4     a      8       1
 3     b      4       0.5

 file2:
 chrm  name  value  new_value
 3     g      6       1
 5     s      12      2
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: I dont know how to involve the second file into a code so I didnt have a initial code to play with. Im new in coding :(

Comment: Go back to the answer you got for merging files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345345/how-to-merge-two-files-with-different-fields-based-on-one-matching-columns   That answer shows how to involve a second file (with `FNR==NR`).

Answer (score 3):

without error handling

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
       FNR==1  {out=FILENAME".new"; print $0, "new_value" > out; next}
               {v=$NF/a[FILENAME]; $++NF=v; print > out}' info file1 file2
```

will generate updated files

```
$ head file{1,2}.new | column -t

==>   file1.new  <==
chrm  name       value  new_value
4     a          8      1
3     b          4      0.5

==>   file2.new  <==
chrm  name       value  new_value
3     g          6      1
5     s          12     2
```

**Explanation**

> `NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}` scan the first file and save the file/value pairs in the associative array
>
> `FNR==1` in the header line of each data file
>
> `out=FILENAME".new"` set a output filename
>
> `print $0, "new_value" > out` print  existing header appended with the new column name
>
> `v=$NF/a[FILENAME]` for every data line, scale the last field and assign to `v`
>
> `$++NF=v` increment number of fields and assign the new computed value to the last field
>
> `print > out` print the new line to the same file set before
>
> `info file1 file2` the list of files should be preceded by the info file

Comment: Thanks Karakfa, but I have 66 files so is there a way to automate it so all 66 files are run in ONE COMMAND ?

Comment: they are not run one by one, as you can see in the example.  As long as you put the `info` file first, you can list the file names on the same command, or if have some common name/directory use globs.  For example `awk ... info file{1,66}` will run the script all 66 files, file1..file66

Comment: Seems great! It would be awesome if you please just shortly explain your command?

Comment: Worked well, Thanks again Karakfa :)

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared the following double nested `awk` command for you:

```
awk 'NR>1{system("awk -v div="$2" -f div_column3.awk "$1" | column -t > new_"$1);}' info.file
```

with div_column3.awk being a `awk` commands script file with the content:

```
$ cat div_column3.awk
NR==1{print $0" new_value"}NR>1{print $0" "$3/div}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I'm not sure when this approach might be useful.